# Get.to(MyPage()) - How to remove all previous routes - Flutter GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes, flutter-getx

I have a simple Flutter app and I want to remove all previous routes but I want to do with GetX, How to do that?

Now it works with

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

But I want to know the correct way with `Get.to` or similar

Answer (score 47):

```
Get.offAll(Home());
```

of with namedRoutes:

```
Get.offAllNamed('/home');
```

More info on docs:
https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md

Answer (score 23):

If you want remove last page then use it.

```
Get.off(Home());
```

If you want remove all previous page then use it.

```
Get.offAll(Home());
```

just simple

Answer (score 9):

for removing last page:

```
Get.off(()=>PageName());
```

for clearing all previous pages:

```
Get.offAll(()=>PageName());
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Get.reset()` this will remove all the previous routes

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 Get.offNamedUntil('home', (route) => false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `Get.reset();`. Please check this [page](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/lib/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart).

```
 /// Clears all registered instances (and/or tags).
 /// Even the persistent ones.
 ///
 /// - [clearFactory] clears the callbacks registered by [Get.lazyPut()]
 /// - [clearRouteBindings] clears Instances associated with Routes when using
 ///   [GetMaterialApp].
 bool reset({bool clearFactory = true, bool clearRouteBindings = true}) =>
  GetInstance().reset(
      clearFactory: clearFactory, clearRouteBindings: clearRouteBindings);
```